# Peculiar behavior: AND without WHERE still works

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I wonder why this query still works perfectly. I thought a WHERE clause always has to start with `WHERE`?

```
    SELECT `persons`.*
    FROM `persons`
    LEFT JOIN `team_memberships`
    ON (`team_memberships`.`participant` = `persons`.`id`)
    JOIN `teams`
    ON (`teams`.`id` = `team_memberships`.`team`)
    JOIN `departments`
    ON (`departments`.`id` = `teams`.`department`)
    JOIN `areas`
    ON (`areas`.`id` = `departments`.`area`)
    JOIN `companies`
    ON (`companies`.`id` = `areas`.`company`)

    [NO WHERE HERE]

    AND `persons`.`id` = ?
```

Comment: Maybe the joins act as an implicit WHERE?  In T-SQL, joins can be written with a WHERE clause, so this could be similar behavior in reverse.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the AND belongs to the last JOIN keyword:
`JOIN companies ON (companies.id = areas.company) AND persons.id = ?`.

Comment: Okay so what does it mean to join with an AND condition? Should I skip WHERE? This happened by accident by the way, it should originally been WHERE there.

Comment: if you need your condition to be in the where part then put it there. there are cases where you need it in your on clause. for example if you are doing a left join and want only special rows from the joined table to be selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've just added an `AND` to your `ON` clause.  The `ON` clause just evaluates to a boolean true or false, and so `AND` and eg `OR` boolean operators are allowed, with all the usual rules about parenthesis etc applying also.

It's often advantageous to move conditions that are specific to a particular joined table, from  your `WHERE` clause and into the appropriate `ON` clause - if for no other reason than to improve readability.

It can make logical* sense to limit the results of a join *before* going on to join on other tables, rather than returning a big result set and then filtering this at the end with a `WHERE` clause.  I say *logical because often the DBMS will optimise your query so that this happens anyhow... but not always... sometimes poorly performing queries can be improved by filtering at the join (and sometimes the opposite is true too).

For example, if you know that you're only interested in people over the age of 25, it makes sense to `JOIN persons ON persons.id = team_memberships.participant AND persons.age > 25`, rather than including *all* the results for the subsequent tables that only pertain to young punks only to filter these results at the end again with your `WHERE persons.age > 25` clause.

My understanding is that join performance is likely to degrade as a result of additional expression(s) in the `ON` clause, in the instance where the additional expression(s):

- causes an evaluation to occur on each row in the join (so my `age > 25` example above might be in this category), or
- rely on non-indexed columns from one/both joined tables, when the join would otherwise have relied only on indexed columns.

So eg it might still prove worthwhile stripping the young punks from the result set at the join even if it makes that particular join slower, because the smaller result set at that point might make a big performance increase for subsequent joins.  But if their inclusion at the join yields only a slight increase in the number of records, it might actually be quicker to just include them at the join and then filter them out at the `WHERE` clause.

But I welcome comments clarifying/correcting my understanding.

---

EDIT: As per @ITroubs comment below, I really should have clarified that if the join is an `INNER JOIN` then the end resultset will be the same regardless of if the additional filter conditions are in the `ON` or `WHERE` clause, but for eg in OP's original example  the `LEFT JOIN ON team_memberships` would yield a completely different resultset if the filter conditions are moved from the `WHERE` to the `LEFT JOIN ... ON ...`.

Comment: If this is the case, where should I put my condition then, as it belongs to the table `persons`, the original table?

Comment: Thanks so much. Changed the query to: `ON (persons.id = ? AND team_memberships.participant = persons.id)`. Brilliant answer.

Comment: @silkfire If it makes sense to you to put it in a `WHERE` clause, do that.  But if you move it up to `LEFT JOIN team_memberships ON team_memberships.participant = persons.id AND persons.id = ?` you'll see that you can (I think*) normalise this to `LEFT JOIN team_memberships ON team_memberships.participant = ?`.  I say *"I think" because I'm not very familiar with MySQL so I'm not 100% sure what the `?` means... ;-)

Comment: Tried your normalization query and it retrieved lots of repeated data :) So I'm sticking to the first solution.

The `?` is a placeholder I use in PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: @silkfire Yep, go with what works, and what makes sense to you ;-)

Comment: @silkfire You have to remember this: `SELECT * from tb1 LEFT JOIN tb2 ON (tb1.idtb2 = tb2.id AND tb2.something = 'foo')` and `SELECT * from tb1 LEFT JOIN tb2 ON (tb1.idtb2 = tb2.id) WHERE tb2.something = 'foo'` result in two absolutely different resultsets! the first one does the `tb2.something = 'foo' test and then the join and the second one does the join first and then the filtering!

Comment: @ITroubs Ooops - of course, I lost sight of the fact that this particular join was a `LEFT`y, hidden amongst all the other `[INNER] JOIN`s. Thanks for pointing that out, have updated my answer to highlight the point you've made.

Answer (score 2):

if I am not mistaken then mysql executes your query as follows:

```
SELECT `persons`.*
FROM `persons`
LEFT JOIN `team_memberships`
ON (`team_memberships`.`participant` = `persons`.`id`)
JOIN `teams`
ON (`teams`.`id` = `team_memberships`.`team`)
JOIN `departments`
ON (`departments`.`id` = `teams`.`department`)
JOIN `areas`
ON (`areas`.`id` = `departments`.`area`)
JOIN `companies`
ON ((`companies`.`id` = `areas`.`company`) AND `persons`.`id` = ?')
```

Answer (score 0):

Last AND is not a part of WHERE clause, it's part of JOIN clause

Answer (score 0):

It works because  you don't actually have a `WHERE` clause, your condition `AND persons.id = ?` is part of the last `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

It effectively means

```
join  `companies` on ON (`companies`.`id` = `areas`.`company`) AND persons.id = ?
```

So, since you are performing inner joins - it's *almost*equvivalent. As soon as you switch to puter joins or complex queries - something will break.

Answer (score -1):

It's valid, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html, but note how they use brackets.